# Force time to be stored without localization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

We are building a Rails application that needs to read data from a database that was created, and is used, by another application that I have no control over.

The other application stores all of its time information in a UTC time field but forces local time to be stored there.

Example:

```
current time:        2014-04-15 11:36:54 -0600
current time in UTC: 2014-04-15 17:36:54 UTC
time stored in db:   2014-04-15 11:36:54 UTC
```

My problem is that Rails wants to convert the local time to UTC when it stores the time.

Is there any way I can tell Rails to not change my times to UTC when it stores them?

**update:**

So what a guess my real question is how can I store local time in the database but still have UTC in my models?

Comment: Do you want Rails to do any timezone manipulation on display?  If not, you can globally set via `config.time_zone = "UTC"`

Comment: UTC is already the default. I tried setting `config.time_zone` to my local time zone and it works.

Comment: My database is still converting it to UTC time though

Comment: Can you try setting the same to you database. Database also has its own timzone.

Comment: I can't change the database as the second application needs to be able to read from it.

Comment: If I change the default timezone it offsets the time again when I find the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set

```
ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone = :local
```

Then it should use the local timezone (as set by the TZ environment variable etc.). It's up to you to manage the local timezone and to take care of any oddities due to the timezone changing (eg if you observe daylight savings time)

Comment: That will still put a time zone offset on the time object though so the database will still convert it to UTC time, will it not?

Comment: Not in my testing - the data was sent to the server with no timezone information